# What is the difference between a (re)skin and a texture?

Tags: team-fortress-2, terminology

When searching through mods for TF2, I came across some confusion.

Creators used the word "skin" to describe a remake of the default skin for objects, including adding sections (see LED Sentry skin).

But "texture" was used to describe a change the lighting/colour or overall texture of the object.

TFMM (Team Fortress Modification Manager) categorizes "skin" and "texture" as 2 different things.

---

What is the difference between the two terms? Or can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A texture is an image that is loaded onto a 3D object is a game world to make it look like its real world counterpart - be it a barrel, a tent, a tree trunk, whatever. A skin is a "special" texture used on weapons in FPSs as well as for heroes in MOBAs (I believe). Usually acquiring a new skin for a weapon in TF2 requires an achievement of some kind, trading, or unlocking crates. A skin is normally visible to all players, and basically makes your weapon look much cooler than everyone else's. In TF2 (since the Gun Mettle update) you can get [many different skins for weapons](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Decorated), which are mostly gained by unlocking crates.

The word "reskin" refers to a new weapon that is functionally indistinguishable from the original but looks different (and often has a different name). Examples are the Postal Pummeler vs Axtinguisher, and the Black Rose vs the Knife.

All skins are textures, but most textures are not skins.

Comment: As a general rule, the word "reskin" refers to a weapon that is otherwise identical to another weapon other than how it looks.

For example, [The Postal Pummeler](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Postal_Pummeler) is a reskin of the [Axtinguisher](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Axtinguisher) as they both have identical stats.

Comment: This is opposed to a skin, which you can download from FPSBanana to replace the model of an existing weapon.

Comment: @Powerlord Oops, didn't notice that part of OP's title. Thanks for the pointer